# Is it possible to create a shortcut in homebrew's name reference?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I have installed mongodb using homebrew and can start the service using this command:

> brew services start mongodb-community@4.2

is there a way to rename the mongodb-community or create an alias to be able to call it like this?

> brew services start mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bash then add following line in `.bashrc` file or if you are using zsh then add in `.zshrc` file

`alias startmongo="mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf"`

Above command will run mongo in foreground and if you close the terminal, mongo process will exit,
but
if you are running
`brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

this will run mongodb process in background as macos service.

Now
`brew services start mongodb`
Above command was in use before mongo 4.2 version.(some licensing changes after 4.0.5, do not know exact reason).

After 4.0.5, there is community and enterprise version of mongodb [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26527603/2987755)

So just to have two different service on same machine, command might have been changed for community version.

`brew services start mongodb-community@4.2`

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb

Comment: Thank you dkb for your answer. I did that indeed. It's even easier.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone is wondering why dkb's solution is not working, you need to close the terminal and restart in order to see the changes.

Comment: You can do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` instead of restarting the terminal (which works because it reloads these files).